# Spring JPA - read a list of entities (with only partial properties) and update value without SELECTING the whole object from database?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I'm using Spring Boot 1.5.2. I have a big Entity with **multiple properties** and multiple **OneToMany** relations, for example:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
class Person {
   @Id
   protected long id;

   private String property1;
   private String property2;
   private String property3;
   private String property4;
   private String property5;
   private String property6;

   @OneToMany
   private List<Obj1> obj1List;
   @OneToMany
   private List<Obj2> obj2List;
   @OneToMany
   private List<Obj3> obj3List;
   @OneToMany
   private List<Obj4> obj4List;


}
```

How can I read the list of `Person` from database, but only with 2 properties `id` and `property2`, and update `property2=0`.

Then, I can use JPA `CrudRepository` to save():

```
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Long> {

}

for (Person person : personList) {
   this.personRepository.save(person)
}
```

I don't want to use `findAll()` from `CrudRepository` which enables Hibernate to SELECT the whole list of Person with a big SQL query before saving to database.

Comment: Why even fetch, update and save. Just write a method that directly does the update.

Comment: @M.Deinum Of course, it needs to fetch the list of objects first to update the property before saving to database.

Comment: No it doesn't. You can just write an update query which does all that without the overhead of retrieving everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your `PersonRepository` interface, you should be able to add a `Query` like this:

```
@Query("select new Person(id, property2) from Person")
List<Person> findIdAndProperty2();
```

The other fields should come back null as they haven't been specified in your query. You'll just need to add a constructor to `Person` with `id` and `property2` as arguments.

For updating, you can use similar syntax...

```
@Modifying
@Query("update Person set property2 = ?1 where id in ?2")
int updateProperty2(String property2, List<Long> ids);
```

`com.google.common.collect.Iterables.partition` can be used to process your updates in chunks. For instance...

```
for (List<Long> curUpdateIds : Iterables.partition(ids, 1000)) {
    personRepository.updateProperty2("0", curUpdateIds);
}
```

Comment: but here I want to update the existing Person. I'm not sure Hibernate will still make a SELECT query to get all properties of this Person entity (even with null) before updating the object.

Comment: @BằngRikimaru gave suggestion for updating